# error al convertir query a datatable entity framework y c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, linq

Quiero pasar el resultado de un query de Entity a un datatable, pero no he podido ya que me genera error de la forma en que lo estoy haciendo usando CopyToDataTable()

> 'No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo
> 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType4`1[System.Int32]]'
> al tipo
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Data.DataRow]'.'

el codigo que uso es:

```html
    public DataTable QueryResultados()
    {
        string situacion;
        if (RadCmbAccion.SelectedValue == "1")
        {
            situacion = "4";
        }
        else
        {
            situacion = "3";
        }

        string valoresCtas = regresa_lista().ToString();

        CatalogoContainer entidad = new CatalogoContainer();        

        IEnumerable<DataRow> query = (IEnumerable<DataRow>)(from c in entidad.CUENTA
                       join ct in entidad.CUENTA_TIPO
                       on c.id_CUENTA_TIPO equals ct.id_CUENTA_TIPO
                       join ffp in entidad.FORMA_PAGO
                       on c.id_FORMA_PAGO equals ffp.id_FORMA_PAGO
                       join cs in entidad.CUENTA_SITUACION
                       on c.id_CUENTA_SITUACION equals cs.id_CUENTA_SITUACION
                       where c.id_CUENTA_SITUACION.Equals(situacion) && valoresCtas.Contains(c.id_CUENTA.ToString())
                       select new
                       {
                           c.id_CUENTA
                       });

        DataTable boundTable = (query.CopyToDataTable());
        return boundTable;
    }
```

Alguien sabra como corregir este error?

Comment: ¿Solo quiere `id_CUENTA` en el DataRow?

Comment: @AmalK no, tengo mas campos, pero solo coloque ese para pruebas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he resuelto mi pregunta quitando

> `IEnumerable<DataRow>`

agregando una clase CambioEstatus() con las propiedades que quiero que se muestren en la query, en este caso con id_CUENTA de tipo int y haciendo una deserealizacion json del resultado de mi query de la siguiente manera

```html
        var query = (from c in entidad.CUENTA
                     join ct in entidad.CUENTA_TIPO
                     on c.id_CUENTA_TIPO equals ct.id_CUENTA_TIPO
                     join ffp in entidad.FACTURA_FORMA_PAGO
                     on c.id_FORMA_PAGO equals ffp.id_FORMA_PAGO
                     join cs in entidad.CUENTA_SITUACION
                     on c.id_CUENTA_SITUACION equals cs.id_CUENTA_SITUACION
                     where c.id_CUENTA_SITUACION == (situacion) && valoresCtas.ToString().Contains(c.id_CUENTA.ToString())
                     select new CambioEstatus()
                     {
                         id_CUENTA = c.id_CUENTA
                     }).ToList();

        DataTable dataTable = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query.ToList()));
        return dataTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema probablemente sea del tipo anónimo. Prueba esto:

```
var query = from c in entidad.CUENTA
        join ct in entidad.CUENTA_TIPO
        on c.id_CUENTA_TIPO equals ct.id_CUENTA_TIPO
        join ffp in entidad.FORMA_PAGO
        on c.id_FORMA_PAGO equals ffp.id_FORMA_PAGO
        join cs in entidad.CUENTA_SITUACION
        on c.id_CUENTA_SITUACION equals cs.id_CUENTA_SITUACION
        where c.id_CUENTA_SITUACION.Equals(situacion) && valoresCtas.Contains(c.id_CUENTA.ToString())
        select c;

DataTable boundTable = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
return boundTable;
```

Comment: Hola @AmalK, cuando alguien realiza una pregunta, no sólo busca un código que copiar y pegar, busca además una explicación de como funciona. Intenta comentar tu código y explicar como funciona y sobre todo, en dónde estaba su error y porqué. Un saludo